# cpu information

Tags: c, linux

I want know how can we find cpu information (Number of cpus and spead of cpu) from c program in linux.
can  anybody help me onthat

Answer (score 6):

You can read from the `/proc/cpuinfo` file to gain information about CPUs in the running  computer.

Answer (score 5):

As Delan has mentioned /proc/cpuinfo does provide those details.

There is also sysconf for getting the number of logical CPU's.

```
long numcpus = sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN);
printf("Number of CPU's=%ld\n",numcpus);
```

Comment: sysconf actually returns a long.